# ng xi18n: exclude code in node_modules when extracting strings

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-i18n

In our Angular app, we are using the Angular i18n mechanism to mark strings as translatable in the component-HTML and we use `ng xi18n` to extract the translatable strings and write them to a xlf file. But besides of our app strings the xlf file does also contain strings from the ng-bootstrap library which we use in our app and which has all of its code in the node_modules folder.

The following xml block is an example which shows one of the strings, we don't want to have in our messages.xlf, but which is also extracted by the `ng xi18n` tool:

```
...
<trans-unit id="ngb.alert.close" datatype="html">
  <source>Close</source>
  <context-group purpose="location">
    <context context-type="sourcefile">node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert.d.ts</context>
    <context context-type="linenumber">3</context>
  </context-group>
</trans-unit>
...
```

Is there a way to not have stuff from node_modules included in the extracted strings? Like some exclude option which can be configured in some place? I could not find anything alike on google, but I wanted to ask here before opening a bug request on the angular-cli github project...

Further detail:

A simple way to reproduce this problem is given with the following steps:

- Create a new Angular app
- Add the line `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.1"` to package.json and run npm install
- Add NgbModule to the imports section in app.module.ts
- Replace the content in app.component.html  by a simple `<div i18n>example text</div>`
- run ng i18n
- Look at the generated messages.xlf

  - You see the "example text" from app.component.html
  - And you see all the strings from ng-bootstrap

Comment: This was now proposed to the Angular team as a new feature and is tracked in Github under https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35223. If this feature is part of any official Angular release at some point in the future I will update this question accordingly.

Comment: any way to solve this?